# Error CS0029 "No se puede convertir implicitamente el tipo void en bool"

Tags: c#

Tengo que hacer las operaciones básicas de una lista: insertar, eliminar y mostrar. El error "no se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo void en bool" aparece cuando quiero llamar el método de insertar.

Mi codigo se compone de una clase llamada LISTA y el program:

```
  class program
    {
        static LISTA listaNueva = new LISTA();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string res;
            do
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("   LISTA SIMPLE ENLAZADA   ");
                Console.WriteLine(" a) Insertar al frente ");
                Console.WriteLine(" g) Salir");
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n¿Opción?");
                res = Console.ReadLine();
                switch (res)
                { case "a": InsertarAlFrente(); break; }
            } while (res != "g");
        }

        static void InsertarAlFrente()
        {   int Dato = 0;
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese un numero entero");
            Dato = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (listaNueva.InsertarInicio(Dato)) //AQUI APARECE EL ERROR
            { Console.WriteLine("\nDato insertado en la lista"); }
            else
            { Console.WriteLine("\nError, no se ha podido insertar"); }
            Console.ReadKey();
       }
}
```

El metodo en la clase "LISTA", (el que mando a llamar) es este;

```
 public void InsertarInicio(int item)
        {   NODO auxiliar = new NODO();
            auxiliar.dato = item;
            auxiliar.siguiente = null;

            if (inicio == null)
            { inicio = auxiliar; }
            else
            {   NODO puntero;
                puntero = inicio;
                inicio = auxiliar;
                auxiliar.siguiente = puntero;
            } 
        }
```

Comment: `InsertarInicio` no retorna nada y lo estás usando como argumento de un `if` que espera una expresión booleana.